# Flutter: Auto Vertical Height in ListView.builder

Tags: flutter, listview, flutter-layout, height

I'm trying to show some Cards with the ListView.builder
I want to set the heights of each card automatically to the height of its children content

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
 Widget _buildListItems(BuildContext context, DocumentSnapshot document) {
  return Center(
   child: Card(
    child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        ListTile(
          title: Text(document['title']),
          subtitle: Text(document['subtitle']),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            child: Text(
              document['summary'],
              softWrap: true,
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
}


@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text('Title'),
    centerTitle: true,
  ),
  body: StreamBuilder(
    stream: Firestore.instance.collection('randomDB').snapshots(),
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
      if (!snapshot.hasData) return const Text('Loading...');
      return ListView.builder(
        itemExtent: 225.0,
        itemCount: snapshot.data.documents.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
            _buildListItems(context, snapshot.data.documents[index]),
      );
    },
  ),
}
```

When document['summary'] is too long, it makes the text overflow through the card widget. For this time all I do is increase itemExtent in ListView.Builder

Is there a way to set the heights of ListView dynamically?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Just add `shrinkWrap: true`.

& Remove  `itemExtent: 225.0,`

```
ListView.builder(
  shrinkWrap: true,
  itemCount:  snapshot.data.documents.length,
  itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
        _buildListItems(context, snapshot.data.documents[index]),
 },
),
```

Comment: this works great and is probably the easiest most flexible solution to setting using `ListView.builder` in a `Column`. Thanks

Comment: One of the best and working solution, saves a lots of time and "Space"! thanks.

Comment: This is awesome my friend

Answer (score 12):

I believe the column has something called the `mainAxisSize` property

```
Column(
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
)
```

`MainAxisSize.min` will make the Column size stretch to the minimum size of the children.
Opposite to it is `MainAxisSize.max` that will stretch to the maximum size that it can achieve.

But I haven't tested it yet tho. Hope it will help

Answer (score 2):

you can use my implementation

```
Widget adapter(List<String> strings){
    List<Widget> widgets= List<Widget>();
    for(int i=0;i<strings.length;i++){
      widgets.add(Text(strings[i]));
    }

    Row row=Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children:widgets
              ),
            ],
          );
    return row;
  }
```

This example displays a list of strings

Answer (score 1):

```
 ListView.builder(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        itemCount: provider.products.length,
                        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                          return InkWell(
                            onTap: () => viewProductDetail(provider.products[index]),
                            child: const OrderDetailsWidgets().orderedProducts(
                              title: provider.products[index].itemName ?? '',
                              price: '---',
                              img: provider.products[index].productImage ??
                                  'request-list-image.png',
                              context: context,
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                      ),
```

adding zero padding for listview.builder reduced the height

Answer (score 0):

Just don't specify the `itemExtent` parameter.

Or just give it a `null` value, instead of `225.0`

This way, the child will get its exact needed height into the `ListView`

Answer (score 0):

**Try**

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
 Widget _buildListItems(BuildContext context, DocumentSnapshot document) {
  return Center(
   child: Card(
    child: Column(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: <Widget>[
        Flexible(
          ListTile(
          title: Text(document['title']),
          subtitle: Text(document['subtitle']),
        ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            child: Text(
              document['summary'],
              softWrap: true,
            ),
          ),
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Just set `shrinkWrap: true`, the listview will automatically take the required height.